# zoom api cmeeting created with wrong start date

Tags: python, zoom-sdk

I'm working on an elearning website and I'm trying to integrate Zoom meetings using the API

According to the [official documentation](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/meetings/meetingcreate), the `start_time` must be set to the `yyyy-MM-ddTH:M:S`.

Example : 2020-10-02T18:00:00

Based on that, this is the code I'm using.

```
class Zoom:

    ...

    def parse_date(self, date):
        parts = date.strip().split(' ')
        part1 = parts[0]
        part2 = parts[1]
        parts1 = part1.split('/')
        day = parts1[0]
        month = parts1[1]
        year = parts1[2]
        parts2 = part2.split(':')
        h = parts2[0]
        m = parts2[1]
        formatted_date = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T' + h + ':' + m + ':00Z'
        return formatted_date

    def create_meeting(self, topic, start_date, password):
        token = self.get_token()
        conn = http.HTTPSConnection(Zoom.ZOOM_API_URL)      
        headers = {'authorization': "Bearer " + token, 'content-type': "application/json"}
        data = {'topic': topic, 'type': 2, 'start_time': self.parse_date(start_date), 'timezone': 'Africa/Casablanca', 'password': password}
        conn.request("POST", "/v2/users/me/meetings", json.dumps(data), headers)
        response = json.loads(conn.getresponse().read().decode('utf-8'))
        return response

zoom = Zoom('API_KEY', 'API_SECRET')
meeting = zoom.create_meeting(topic='Learning test', start_date='02/10/2020 18:00', password='123456')
```

The meeting is created but the start date is ignored as shown in the image

[image]

As you can see I specified 6 PM as a start date but it's 7 PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was caused by the `Z` at the end of the date. After removing it the date hour is no longer incremented.